# Pluriel en -oux (poux, choux, etc.)

Tags: pluriel, histoire

La kyrielle très connue :

> Bijou, chou, pou, hibou, joujou, caillou, genou.

Pourquoi ces sept noms en -ou font leur pluriel en -x ?

(Neuf si on rajoute tripoux et ripoux.)

Comment: On peut ajouter *ripoux*

Comment: @jlliagre et tripoux☺.

Comment: @jlliagre j'ai vu ripous aussi.

Comment: https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Ripoux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On peut lire sur [cet article](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluriel_des_noms_communs_fran%C3%A7ais_en_%C2%AB_ou_%C2%BB) de Wikipédia :

> La linguiste (et historienne de l’orthographe française) Nina Catach (1923-1997), avance les explications suivantes :
>
> « Pour les mots en -ou, comme clou(s) / pluriel clous, l’Académie donne le pluriel en s, sauf pour ceux qui finissaient anciennement par un l mouillé, comme pou / poux (ancien français pouil), genou / genoux, verrou / verroux (Acad. genouil, verrouil jusqu’en 1762, puis pluriel verrous). Pour chou(x), la présence ancienne du l final (1606 choul) a également favorisé le maintien du x final au pluriel (cf. ciel / cieux). »

Comment: La raison sous-jacente est que les moines copistes utilisaient un signe qui ressemblait à la lettre **X** comme raccourci de **US**.  Ce signe est devenu par erreur un vrai **X** alors que le **U** était rétabli pour préserver la prononciation. On retrouve ce **X** final dans les nombreux mots au pluriel en **X** comme *chevaux* et autres.

Comment: C'est ce qui se lit dans la suite de l'article, en moins explicatif: « Bijoux (de la couronne) : Il y a deux sortes de reliques : les monuments et les grigris. On me dit que l’écriture du français est un monument historique. Je le veux bien. Le Sacré-Cœur, même très laid, est un monument historique. L’x des sept pluriels en -oux (qui sont huit avec chouchoux comme les Trois Mousquetaires étaient quatre) n’est qu’un grigri ridicule, fantaisie abréviative pour -us au Moyen Âge[...]@jlliagre

Comment: En fin de compte, ce que vous appelez la raison sous-jacente serait *la* raison, l'occurrence du l mouillé n'étant qu'une coïncidence?@jlliagre